# how to make fixed div occupy full page dinamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

This isn't exactly easy because the div that's occupying the whole page is not a wrapper of the content that's on top of it. Let me show you.

the html looks like this:

```css
.closeModal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.modal.contentModal {
  width: 35%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="closeModal"></div>
  <div class="contentModal"> RANDOM CONTENT INSIDE </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, a modal pops up but its height is unknown because the content inside ".contentModal" is dynamic.

the purpose of the .closeModal is to occupy the area behind the .contentModal and when the user clicks outside .contentModal it should close .modal
The problem with what I'm doing is if the content generates a .contentModal with a larger height than the screen height, below that area, I click but it won't leave the modal.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZlWeboVgjRMxtSda15m?p=preview) where you can test what I just said.

Scroll and then click at the bottom of the page and you'll see it wont leave the modal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `.modal.contentModal` means ONE element has BOTH classes.  
Use `.modal .contentModal` instead

Comment: add `max-height:90%; overflow:auto` to `.contentModal` css... or any lower value

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i have them separately

Comment: @AbbasNabilou that will make the scroll bar show up at the center div. Doesnt seem to be a pretty solution.

Comment: What if U use fixed position on the closeModal too ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1N1qBnkWrJsr3M8gaxZd?p=preview

Comment: @DaniP well spotted! thank you very much :)

Comment: @DaniP and there's a small problem again. if you have the mouse outside the content div, i.e. in the .closeModal div the page won't scroll

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but it works.. You could place your `closeModal` inside your `contentModal` and have two of it, one to the left and one to the right. Like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="contentModal">
  <div class="closeModal left" ng-click="leaveModal()"></div>
  <div class="closeModal right" ng-click="leaveModal()"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.closeModal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.closeModal.right {
  right: -100%;
  left: 100%;
}

.closeModal.left {
  right: 100%;
  left: -100%;
}
```

Here's an updated fork of your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwcvuzBnKbLoF26dZbcl?p=preview) after applying the changes above.

Note: I specified `left` and `right` as `-100%` because you have set `35%` on their parent (which is a third of the screen), so these two `closeModal`s will fill the other two thirds.

Comment: It works, thank you! I also got"cleaner" answer though. Thank you  for your time and effort :)